# manually configure browser location

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, proxy, geolocation

I'm using a work computer behind a corporate proxy.  Because the proxy is in a different state, websites that identify location think I am in a completely different location than I actually am.  Is there a way to force my browser (both Firefox and Chrome) to identify as being in my actual location rather than automatically (and incorrectly) detecting it?

Comment: That is something the particular website would have to implement.  It sounds like they are currently using IP based geo-location.

Comment: @heavyd so no??

Comment: So, no, the website would have to change how they are determining your location.    They could use the browser's Geolocation API which should then give more accurate results, but that requires a change on their part.

Answer (score 1):

Try the browser extension: Location Guard.  This extension provides a nice interface for spoofing the [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) and provides other features (ie: location randomization).

[Location Guard - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/location-guard/cfohepagpmnodfdmjliccbbigdkfcgia)

[Location Guard :: Add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/location-guard/)